# No startup: "cannot find 'writable' partition"

Tags: 16.04, startup, fstab, plymouth

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and an old Windows XP install) on a 32bit Notebook. Today, Ubuntu didn't start up anymore. The error messages I get after choosing Ubuntu in GRUB are the following:

```
/scripts/init-premount/plymouth: line 38: /sbin/plymouthd: not found

/scripts/init-premount/plymouth: line 38: /bin/plymouth: not found

grep: /proc/device-tree/model: No such file or directory
```

So I interrupted startup after nothing had happened for a few minutes and chose Ubuntu's recovery mode in GRUB. It also gets stuck at a point where the following messages pop up after some time:

```
grep: /proc/device-tree/model: No such file or directory

random: nonblocking pool is intialized

findfs: unable to resolve 'LABEL=writable'

done.

cannot find 'writable' partition
```

After that, it goes into BusyBox. I checked `/etc/mtab` and saw that `/dev/sda1` was not mounted, I tried `mount /dev/sda1 /root`, which works fine, the partition looks good, I can see the home directory is intact. Also, `fstab` has not been changed for a long time and still contains the correct UUID identifier for the Ubuntu partition.

Hard drive partitions: `/dev/sda1` is the Linux partition containing Ubuntu, `/dev/sda2` is an NTFS partition with Windows XP, `/dev/sda3` is a swap partition. GRUB is working fine, I get to choose Ubuntu and its recovery mode, and Windows. Windows works perfectly fine. I didn't know what to do, so I used a Boot-Repair Disk to repair GRUB, just in case, so GRUB still works fine, but Ubuntu still doesn't. What could I do?

Comment: Can you boot with an older kernel?  Are you using lABEL= anywhere in the fstab?

Comment: @ubfan1 I cannot choose any other kernel in grub. fstab does not contain anything with "LABEL=" (ext4 partition and swap partition listed by "UUID=", ntfs partition as "/dev/sda2" and a remote sshfs partition by a nickname defined somewhere in ~/.ssh)

Comment: Any suggestions at bootup to run fsck?   If errors, the disk might come up read only.

Comment: @ubfan1 I didn't see any. Fsck reports /dev/sda1 to be fine. Startup still impossible though.

Comment: Looks like your initial ram disk (initrd) isn't good.  Did you rebuild your kernel or do something which would have affect initrd?

Comment: @ubfan1 I didn't, at least not knowingly. But I noticed that ever since I release-upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, although sources.list looks normal and apt-get updates fine, there has not been a single package to be upgraded in an entire month, whenever I apt-get upgrade'd.

Comment: @ubfan1 I used the rescue CD to create a new initrd with update-initramfs and update-grub, but nothing changed. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how my last few neurons got to this conclusion, but after hours of searching and staring at [this mail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snappy-devel/2016-April/001729.html) and [this diff](https://code.launchpad.net/~mvo/ubuntu/wily/initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core/new/+merge/269945), they concluded that maybe ubuntu-core was the culprit. So I uninstalled everything I found related to it:

```
2017-05-24 15:52:54 remove initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core:all 0.7.43 <nessuna>
2017-05-24 15:52:54 remove ubuntu-core-config:all 0.6.40 <nessuna>
```

And it worked eventually! Probably `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core` put a bugged script into `initrd` somewhere in the past updates.

Other two words about this kind of bugs:

1. they're really hard to catch, `debug=y` and `systemd.log_level=debug` in the kernel command line are of some help, but tracking exactly who is doing what is really difficult.
2. to reinstall may sound as an attractive option after hours of debugging/rebooting, but it's a very short-term solution. Almost always the right approach is to understand what's causing the bug, solve it and write down the solution for your future self and others.

Comment: You're absolutely genius. I was struggling with my Ubuntu for 3 days! Thank you hero! :D

Comment: Ahah thank you! It's always rewarding to see that all this blood and sweat has helped someone else!

Comment: It happened again today setting up my brand new Raspberry Pi 4 and I managed to spend a couple of hours on this problem again. The culprits should be `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/resize` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/ubuntu-core-rootfs` in `initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core_0.7.45_all.deb`:

`resize:22:wait-for-root "LABEL=writable" "${ROOTDELAY:-180}" >/dev/null || true`

Both have these nice `wait-for-root  "LABEL=writable"` that make absolutely no sense in a system without `snap`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299840, their solution was to reinstall, but not format the target partitions.  Backup everything first of course.